# Datatables Plugin - Error When Reload Ajax without losing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem with Datatables plugin, because I need to reload the Ajax Data without losing the current page

I know that with

```
table.ajax.reload(null,false)
```

Will work, but, if I'm on the last page, and the user deletes all rows, there is an error because there are not more elements on that page, I do not know how to correct de error

I tried with:

```
table.ajax.reload(null,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my own opinion instead of using `table.ajax.reload(null, false)`, you can use a different approach.

You can just do something like this:

```js
let currentPage = table.page(); // To get the current page number
table.ajax.reload(function(data){
    // Success callback
    if (data.length === 0 && currentPage > 0) {
        // Incase there are no more rows
        table.page(currentPage - 1).draw('page'); // Go to the previous page and redraw the table
    } else {
        table.page(currentPage).draw('page'); // Reload the current page
    }
}, false);
```

By checking if there are no more rows `(data.length === 0)` and the current page is not the first page `(currentPage > 0)`, you can handle the scenario where the user deletes all rows on the last page. In that case, the code moves to the previous page `(table.page(currentPage - 1))` and redraws the table `(draw('page'))`. Otherwise, if there are still rows or the current page is the first page, it simply reloads the current page `(table.page(currentPage).draw('page'))`.

Let me know if this works!